# Approximation for $\log( 1+\exp(-|a|) )$ with $a \in \Re$

Tags: probability, logarithms, power-series

If one is adding probabilities as log probabilities lp and lq so that $lsum =\max(lp,lq)+\log(1+\exp(-|lp-lq|))$ it would be nice to have a slightly less computationally expensive correction to the max term. I known that $\log(1+x) = x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4$ etc. However firstly that's not great for x=1 and also I would think there was more that could be done since $x = \exp(-|a|)$. Reasonable ranges of a are from 0 to 10. Any thoughts?

Comment: series expansion around $a=0$ for $log(1+exp(-a))$? check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BLog%5B1+%2B+Exp%5B-a%5D%5D,%7Ba,0,4%7D%5D)

Comment: I checked that series approximation but it requires very high order to not become very divergent for reasonable ranges of a. You can truncate to zero when a is reasonably large but I think that would be maybe for a>10 or so. Even 4th order is no good above a=2.

Comment: How approximate can you get away with? You could write $\log(1+\exp(-|a|)) \sim \log(2)\exp(-|a|)$ for something that behaves similarly but is systematically smaller. You can add a constant $\log(1+\exp(-|a|)) \sim \log(2)\exp(-0.85|a|)$ and the approximation might be a little better.

Comment: You could do your expansion around $a =5$ instead of $a = 0$. I.e., the midpoint of the range you want to compute over, not one end.